# Run-time error “440”: The object does not support this method

Tags: excel, vba

I try to send multiple emails with attachements. The macro crashes with the error 440, by the line of .Send . Sometimes it crashes after 50 sent emails, sometimes after 30, 80, 100. What can be wrong?

Is it problem connected with Outlook, Excel, security settings?

I havent found any solution regarding this problem on any site.

```
Set rangepro = Worksheets("Mappings").Range("f2:f" & rangeprojects)

For Each cell In rangepro                        'loops every project in rangepro, this name is used later in the filter to generate the files

    Worksheets("27a Report").Range("A1:au" & range27a).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.Value

    'Select only the visible cells in active sheet
    Worksheets("27a Report").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy

    '~~> Source/Input Workbook
    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    '~~> Set the relevant sheet from where you want to copy
    'Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

    With wbO

        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")

        ActiveSheet.Name = "27a Report"

        wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                     SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        Call GeneratePivots.CreatePivot1

        Call checkiftravel

        ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Path = "\\wrofs1\sd&m\OnePMO\01.Services\03.Operations\05.Industrialization\Tools\27a\" & f & d & "\"

        .SaveAs Filename:=Path & cell.Value & d & "-NBTReport.xls", FileFormat:=56

        .Close

        'send the email
        eSubject = Worksheets("Mail").Range("c2").Value
        eBody = Worksheets("Mail").Range("c5").Value
        eOnBehalf = Worksheets("Mail").Range("c26").Value
        'eAttach = Range("f27").Value

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        OutApp.Session.Logon
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = eOnBehalf
            .To = cell.Offset(0, 1)
            '.cc = ccAll
            .Subject = eSubject
            .body = eBody
            '.Attachments.Add eAttach
            .Attachments.Add Path & cell.Value & d & "-NBTReport.xls"
            .Display
            .Send
        End With

    End With

Next cell
```

Comment: Hi Ben, to be honest I dont know what is incorrect about the indentation :(

Comment: fixed! Thank you :) Still waiting for any help thought :D

Comment: whats the value of cell.value in `Path & cell.Value & d & "-NBTReport.xls"` when it crashs ?

Comment: I suggest you move `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` and `OutApp.Session.Logon` outside the loop.

Comment: That is the name of the project. One cell on the right we have the email of the person that should get specific file.

Comment: and does that particular file exists ? maybe the name is not equal

Comment: Try this. Replace the line `.Display` with `DoEvents` and now try it.